# How to change Sublime Text default save location?

Tags: macos, save, sublimetext3

When I write something in the empty canvas of Sublime Text and try to save it, it defaults to `/` (macOS) which can get irritating.

How can I change the default save dialog location or current working directory of sublime text to say `~/Downloads/Test` ?

I normally launch the app by GUI, but if a CLI solution (like environment variable) is there, which I can use as an alias, it'd be okay too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this page they address a similar question to yours https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/setting-to-change-the-default-save-location/50989. You can make minimal sublime text plugin to save files to a fixed path, you can then bind this it to a any key, even override the default save key.

```py
import sublime
import sublime_plugin

class CustomSaveCommand(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):

    def run(self, edit):
        # Replace the my_custom_path with the absolute path you want.
        self.view.settings().set("default_dir", "my_custom_path")
        self.view.run_command("save")
```

Then bind it to the same keys as save: <kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd>

Also this plugin can help you [AdvancedNewFile](https://github.com/skuroda/Sublime-AdvancedNewFile#features), you can set aliases to get to the path you want faster, or modify in the plugin settings `default_path` to the path you want.

Comment: Link-only answers are generally not acceptable on Stack Exchange sites. The link may change or become unreachable in the future, and without a summary of what the link contains this answer would be useless. Please summarize what is in the link (**don't** just copy and paste) and use the link solely for reference. If you remove the link and the answer cannot stand on its own, it is not a good answer.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense, I expanded my answer, thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 3):

For a GUI solution on macOS, in Sublime Text go to Preferences -> Settings, then paste `"default_dir": "your/favorite/path"`

And you are done.

More info here: https://sublime-text-unofficial-documentation.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/settings.html#file-and-directory-settings